# When does a system of two bivariate polynomials not have roots at infinity?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have no background in algebraic geometry, and I have the following (probably) basic question. Let $p,q\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be polynomials of degree $d$, and consider the  system:
$$ p(x,y) = 0, \qquad q(x,y) = 0. $$
This system has a common root at infinity if the corresponding homogenized system:
$$ p_h(t,x,y) = t^d p(x/t,y/t)=0, \qquad q_h(t,x,y) = t^d q(x/t,y/t)=0 $$
has a solution $(t^*,x^*,y^*)$ with $t^*=0$. Does there exists a simple criterion on the polynomial coefficients which states when something like this cannot occur?

Comment: I suppose you don't want the solution $(t^*,x^*,y^*)=(0,0,0)$. When you put $t=0$ in $p_h$ and $g_h$ you are left with their terms that have largest total degree (${}=d$). The condition would be that the system of these two leaving forms equal to zero has only the solution $x=y=0$.

Comment: leading* forms, not leaving forms.

Comment: Yes that makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If the homogeneous polynomials which are the highest-degree portions of $p$ and $q$ are coprime, there is no common root at infinity. One way you can test this coprimality without finding any roots of these polynomials is by computing the [homogeneous resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Homogeneous_resultant) of the top-degree terms: if the resultant is nonzero, the top-degree terms are coprime and have no common root at infinity.

Comment: On the other hand, if the highest-degree portions of  and  have a common divisor, let's say $h$, the homogenized system has an infinite number of solutions characterized by all point at which $h$ evaluates to zero. However since $t=0$, all these points refer to the same point at "infinity". Is this the correct way to think about it?

Comment: Sort of - it's important to remember where you're asking for solutions when you look at equations. You're asking for solutions on a copy of $\Bbb P^1$ which is the line at infinity, so if $[a:b]$ is a solution so is $[ca:cb]$ for any nonzero $c$ and in fact these are the same point.